# SSRS - date parameter does not show calendar control in WebKit browsers

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services, safari

I developed a set of SSRS reports in SSDT(2012). All of my parameters set to have Data type = "Date/Time" should have the ability to accept values via the calendar control.

This is how these parameters behave by default in IE, but I don't get this functionality in Safari (see below), Mobile Safari, or Chrome.

**This is how I want it to behave (as in IE):**
[image]

**This is how it behaves in Safari/Chrome:**
[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is not an officially supported browser for SSRS reports, and would not be surprised if there are issues with other non-IE browsers. [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/f50eb196-3f15-408d-acb7-7f90e3348e3e). Also, [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8b82ca3e-ffd8-4724-a8ac-e7f3fe90b0a8/) talk about the calendar not working in Safari.

Are the users absolutely needing to use those browsers? If so, I would have them manually type in the date. I would type the parameter as something like "Not visited since (ex. 1/20/2012):"

Comment: Honestly, typing in the values is much easier. IE doesn't render the calendar control in SSRS very speedily. You could type the date three times before the calendar even renders sometimes.

Comment: Agreed. However, sometimes they need to use the calendar to find something like the first Monday of a month. So, in the scenarios where they do not already know the date value they want to pass, having the calendar there does help (although they could use the built-in calendar in Windows).

Comment: thanks Neil. this will do for now, but i'd like to keep this open just in case someone else has a suggestion for a fix. in the forum post you linked me to, the MSFT moderator wrote that the report viewer supports Safari. my main interest is having this functionality available in Safari and Mobile Safari.

Comment: I do not think it works with Safari. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8b82ca3e-ffd8-4724-a8ac-e7f3fe90b0a8/

Comment: Thanks Neil. I'll stick with your suggestion to label the parameter "Not visited since (ex. 1/20/2012)"

Comment: Glad I could help. It is unfortunate that you aren't able to get the functionality.